# Specific term for perception bias of content

Tags: phrase-requests

People from Rancho Cucamonga are special.

If a movie is filmed or set in their town, they unswervingly feel that the movie is better than others.  Especially since it is so rare and … special.

They argue online about its greatness, and do not understand how it is that other people don't see the movie's obvious magnificence.  They are genuinely perplexed.

It doesn't have to be a small town.  It could just as easily be ..Scotland, although the rarity of showing Rancho Cucamonga makes it just so *obviously* better, and perhaps what provides the perceptual extra gravitas.

What is the exacting term for this specific kind of bias?

Comment: Hometown bias. Goes along quite nicely with hometown advantage. Hometown folks feel pride in their little corner of the vineyard, and consequently they can't (or won't) admit that something bad came out of something so obviously good; namely, their beloved hometown.

Comment: Hispanophilia bias?

Comment: *We're Number 1!* (repeat repeatedly and loudly).

Answer (score 4):

I have the perfect word in my mother tongue; too bad this is english.SE...

Try **[provincialism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/provincialism?s=t)**, especially #4. I know it is not the most fitting, but what you describe is akin to patriotism and, after all,

> Patriotism is, fundamentally, a conviction that a particular country is the best in the world because you were born in it.

G.B. Shaw

As suggested in the comments, other options are **[parochialism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parochialism)** and **[chauvinism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chauvinism)**

Comment: Or modify patriotism to `local patriotism`

Comment: @Drew Oh I know, the word I had in my was *campanilismo* :)

Comment: Care to add [parochialism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parochialism) (even [narrower mindset](http://the-difference-between.com/parochial/provincial)) and [chauvinism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chauvinism) (broader transgression) for further comparison? You nailed the word I was going suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be a form of the *mere-exposure effect*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mere-exposure_effect